# Elastic Agent kubernetes container logs not shipping from nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have a problem with elastic agents on k8.

Both Elastic Stack (v8.7) and k8 (v1.25 with cri-o; 1 master, 3 nodes) are deployed on local environment, we have 3 clusters (same config for all), all clusters behave the same, regardless of subnet (one cluster is on the same subnet as elastic, others are on different subnets). All clusters have kube-state-metrics deployed on them, as per prerequisites of kubernetes integration.

When deploying agents on k8 with provided .yaml daemonset from elastic, agents rollout fine, there is a healthy status. Policy is configured with system and kubernetes integrations.

In Infrastructure view all containers are populated correctly, metrics seem to populate just fine. **But** when I'm trying to get container logs, I'm only able to get logs from master and node-01, regardless of cluster.

System logs are sent just fine, so I'm leaning towards either agent kubernetes integration problems or cluster configuration errors, but I don't even know what to search for at this stage...

Any suggestions where to look now?

Pods have /var/log/ path mounted correctly, have access to /var/log/containers/ path and logs in it. I can cat them just fine, so it's not a permission issue.

In elastic-agent diagnostics report, in \components\filestream-default there are outputs for pods from node-01 on reports from node-02 and node-03 agents,

Tried redeploying agents, deploying standalone agents, with no avail.